# Can someone suggest me a book for $L^{p}$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, book-recommendation, function-spaces

I am reading functional analysis. I understand all the definitions, theorems, etc. But I am facing a problem in $L^p$ spaces.I am facing problems in understanding the relations like $L^p\subset L^{q}$,$L^p+L^q$,$L^p\cap L^q$, etc. Also finding difficult to construct counterexamples.So if someone suggests to me some book to understand all this that will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Most measure theory texts have a chapter, or at least a section or two, on $L^p$ spaces. A better than average such chapter is Chapter 8 -- $L^p$ *Classes* (pp. 126-144) -- in [**Measure and Integral**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824764994) by Richard L. Wheeden and Antoni Zygmund (1977). I like it because many explicit examples for various inclusions are given, it includes results for an arbitrary measurable subset $E$ of ${\mathbb R}^n$ and not just for $[0,1]$ (and indicates counterexamples when $E$ has infinite measure), discusses results and non-results for $0<p<1,$ **(continued)**

Comment: clear distinction between metric space and normed space and inner product space results, in the case of $p=2$ it gives an introduction to orthogonal/orthonormal systems and Parseval's formula and the Riesz-Fischer theorem, etc. Although in this book the integral is defined in a way that is not all that standard (see [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/321970/15780)), you only need the basic properties of the integral (which are available and used by this chapter), such as monotone convergence theorem, dominated convergence theorem, etc.

Comment: Read a Probability theory book and a partial differential equations book. By constantly working with $L^p$, you will get comfortable. https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html is a good probability book. Folland's PDE book is a good PDE book. There are many other good books in these areas though.

Comment: I do like Wheeden & Zygmund's a lot, and I now there is a newer edition of the classic book. I own a copy of the first edition. Another book, that may be of interest is the Real Analysis volume of the late Elly Stein along with Rami Shakarchi (academic grandson of the late Elly) which were written for highly motivated undergraduates at Princetown, but which is used in many graduate programs (in America and Canada) as a reference and/or source of problems.